# I got a error about Type gradle error marker

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I got this error yesterday and don't know how to fix it. Please help me to solve it！

> org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.UnsupportedConfigurationException: Project eclipseCode location matches workspace root F:\eclipseCode
> Project eclipseCode location matches workspace root F:\eclipseCode

[image]

[image]

Comment: `eclipseCode` is the name of your project, right? Please tell what is your workspace directory and the project directory. Both should not be the same, but according to the error message they are the same.

Comment: My workspace directory is “eclipseCode”, but I don't remember creating a project called ‘’eclipseCode‘’

Comment: What's the full path (see _File > Switch Workspace > Other..._)? In _Project > Properties: Resource_ see _Location_ to get the directory of your project.

Comment: I reinstalled the gradle plugin and the problem was solved. thank you very much